# HTML Table header Grouping with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to group the table header according to the same content.

```
 <table id="tblSample" border="1" >
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Group#1</th><th>Group#1</th><th>Group#1</th><th>Group#21</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Sub-Group#1</th><th>Sub-Group#1</th><th>Sub-Group#2</th><th>Sub-Group#2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>   </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I want to merge the columns Group#1 as asingle column and Sub-Group#1 as well as. Any Idea?
I tried a code but it doesn't worked.
Here is my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/L3ab1edw/1/

expected output:
    `-------------------------------------------------------
   Group#1              |              Group#2
------------------------|---------------------------------
   Sub-Group#1          |     Sub-Group#2 
-----------|------------|------------|---------------------
1          |2           |3           |4`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblSample').each(function () {
        var Column_number_to_Merge = 1;
          var Previous_TH = null;
        var i = 1;
        $("thead",this).find('tr').each(function () {
                var Current_th = $(this).find('th:nth-child(' + Column_number_to_Merge + ')');

            if (Previous_TH == null) {

                Previous_TH = Current_th;
                i = 1;
            } 
            else if (Current_th.text() == Previous_TH.text()) {

                Current_th.remove();

                Previous_TH.attr('colspan', i + 1);
                i = i + 1;
            } 
            else {

                Previous_TH = Current_th;
                i = 1;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly do you want something like that in the end...
<table id="tblSample" border="1" >

    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Group#1</th><th>Group#2</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Sub-Group#1</th><th>Sub-Group#2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>4</td></tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 1):

Use `colspan`:

```
 <table id="tblSample" border="1" >
    <tbody>
        <tr><th colspan="3">Group#1</th><th>Group#21</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Sub-Group#1</th><th>Sub-Group#1</th><th>Sub-Group#2</th><th>Sub-Group#2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>   </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't understand why you need a jQuery to do such a simple task, but here you go:

```
$("#tblSample")
    .find("tbody tr:first-child")
    .html('<th colspan="3">Group#1</th><th>Group#21</th>');
```

Comment: Actually I want a jQuery function to merge it.

Comment: @Rose Added jQuery solution?